# What are all the sword moves in the Wii version of Twilight Princess?

Tags: nintendo-wii, zelda-twilight-princess

I want to jump back into this game and complete it, but I've forgotten what all the secret techniques are that you get from the wolf and how to use them. Can someone list them?

Comment: Are you playing it for NGC or for Wii?

Comment: Wii (12 more..)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Ending Blow** – When enemy is on the ground, target with <kbd>Z</kbd>, then attack with <kbd>A</kbd>

**Shield Attack** – Target enemy with <kbd>Z</kbd>, then move nunchuk sharply forward.

**Back Slice** – Target enemy with <kbd>Z</kbd>, hold <kbd>←</kbd> or <kbd>→</kbd> on the nunchuk and press <kbd>A</kbd> to dodge.  Hit <kbd>A</kbd> again to roll, then swing the Wiimote to attack.

**Helm Splitter** – Perform a shield attack, then hit <kbd>A</kbd>.

**Jump Strike** – Target enemy with <kbd>Z</kbd>, hold <kbd>A</kbd> until your sword charges then release <kbd>A</kbd>.

**Mortal Draw** - With your sword sheathed, and *not* targeting an enemy, wait for the game to prompt you (usually just as an enemy attacks), then press <kbd>A</kbd>.

**Great Spin** – Shake the nunchuk left and right.  Must be at full health.